# How to reset Phusion passenger Ruby on Rails cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

How can I remove the cache of my rails webapp ?

I'm going CRAZY !

Comment: You can generally run `touch tmp/restart.txt` from your rails app root to restart the passenger server. What issues are you experiencing?

Comment: A restart should clear any cache. You might have outdated code on the server.

Comment: Are you talking about the cache for your code or the view cache?

Comment: Going through same issue.  turned off all caching, touched restart.txt, still serving cached file.  rails tmp/cache is 
empty.  Does Phusion have an explicit folder where I can just
go in and delete cached files myself?

Answer (score 4):

Running passenger with nginx, this was the only solution that worked for me.
On the server, run:

```
    passenger-config restart-app
```

See: https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/nginx/restart_app.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you try this?
`Rails.cache.clear`

You maybe using some other cache store, if so `rake tmp:cache:clear` will do nothing since no cached on the file system.